# If I compile a programme in C using linux library, can I use it on windows?

Tags: c, linux, windows, compilation

I just wanted to know if i can use a program that I compiled in c using linux library on windows and if it is possible how to turn it into an `exe` that can be launched like firefox or other software.

I saw that cross compiler could be used in order to create a `.exe` file but I use libraries like `libcurl` or `csfml` (which were downloaded for linux uses).

If you have any advice I am interested.

TLDR: can I compile on linux using linux library for exclusive windows use in .exe and how?

Comment: [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) can run linux program directly on windows, under some conditions....

Comment: I think you should look at the java. Since your main priority seems to be cross-platform and cross-compiling. C can be cross-platform but you will need to compile it in windows too. And if C is must then you can look at wsl/2

Comment: Sadly i am not proefficient in java, i am an intern and one of my collegue asked me to do a programme that interacted with some website.
i am nearly good in c and okay in python if that help

Comment: If you are okay with Python, forget C and do it in Python. It will be way easier to make it work on all platforms. For the record though, both libcurl and csfml exist for Windows also.

Comment: Okay thanks ^^
i will follow the advices and use python, selenium might work quite well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer: No. If you're using libraries across different platforms it's because they are being recompiled on that operating system. The C standard is cross architecture so long as there is a compiler for that specific architecture. Windows uses what's called the PE(Portable Executable) File Format. It's basically a header at the start of each executable which gives clear instructions on how and where in memory the operating system should execute that file. Unix on the other hand uses ELF. MacOS uses the Mach-o. They all carry instructions on how they should be executed. So if you could emulate the PE format on Linux then yes you could run an executable on Linux but compiled on Windows. But the idea of standards and cross platform libraries is so that you can run your code on pretty much any supported architecture. It's not compile once run anywhere, like Java is. But you have to keep in mind the JRE is very similar to a compiler. That JRE has to be compiled for each specific architecture to understand and execute the Java bytecode. So compiling your code anywhere isn't so bad.

If I remember correctly curl and csfml are cross platform libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have something specifically claiming to be a cross compiler, then it generally won't work.

And, if you are running anything more than a plain console window/DOS app, then you'll have to write the code with Windows specific functions. Opening a window, adding a push button, etc, will be different on different platforms.